# Search for a string in a filename in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

`File search` in Eclipse searches for text in files, but not for text in the file **names**. For example I would like a list of all files in my projects that are named `test.py`.

Is this possible in Eclipse?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try Search > File Search. Left "Containing text" empty and enter your pattern (e.g. `*est*` in "File name patterns". Set scope to e.g. "Workspace"